# Solr SearchComponent get all documents

Tags: java, solr

I'm just writing a solr plugin (SearchComponent) and want to iterate over all documents that are found for the query. This is the part of my code in the process method:

```
    // Searcher to search a document
    SolrIndexSearcher searcher  = rb.req.getSearcher();
    // Getting the list of documents found for the query
    DocList docs = rb.getResults().docList;
    // Return if no results are found for the query
    if (docs == null || docs.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    // Get the iterator for the documents that will be returned
    DocIterator iterator = docs.iterator();
    // Iterate over all documents and count occurrences
    for (int i = 0; i < docs.size(); i++) {
        try {
            // Getting the current document ID
            int docid = iterator.nextDoc();
            // Fetch the document from the searcher
            Document doc = searcher.doc(docid);
            // do stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

For now I found a method where I can iterate over all documents that will be returned by i.e. if 1300 documents are found for the query and I only return 20, I will only iterate over 20 with this method for now. I there a possibility to get the full set of documents (1300)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility to do that. You use DocList which contains only 'rows' docs starting from 'start'. If you want to iterate over all 'numFound' docs - use DocSet via

```
rb.getResults().docSet
```

For understanding of this mechanism - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_get_ALL_the_matching_documents_back.3F_..._How_can_I_return_an_unlimited_number_of_rows.3F

Comment: I already tried this, but I'm getting a nullpointer exception. Do you know why this could be null at this stage?

Comment: Easy solution (probably not very nice). Could you make your query with param `rows=1300`, so you will get all your docs in docList

Comment: No, I really want to figure out for the future

Comment: For your understanding - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_get_ALL_the_matching_documents_back.3F_..._How_can_I_return_an_unlimited_number_of_rows.3F

Comment: @Johnny000, so did i answer your question? I've copy my comment to answer

Comment: @Johnny000 docSet is not necessarily defined unless your search component requests it by overriding the `prepare(ResponseBuilder rb)` method and calling: `rb.setNeedDocSet(true);` inside the method. If your class does this, then QueryComponent defines and populates docSet, and it is available to your search component, assuming that your search component is called after QueryComponent.

Comment: Thanks Kai, that was the missing part in my class... (Y)